# Can't delete bot message discord.py / pycord)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I am having trouble deleting discord bot's message. Here is the code to replicate the problem I am having:

```
import discord
from tools.config import TOKEN

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready and online!")

@bot.slash_command(name="chat", description="Тут можно добавить описание")
async def chat(ctx, msg):
        bot_msg = await ctx.respond(f'some message with tagging {ctx.author.mention}')
        await bot_msg.delete(delay=5)   

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

And I get the error:

```
await bot_msg.delete(delay=5)
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

I am using **py-cord==2.4.1** but I believe it's the same thing as **discord.py**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pycord` is not the same as `discord.py`.

> discord.py is a modern, easy to use, feature-rich, and async ready API wrapper for Discord.

`Pycord` is a fork of `discord.py`.

### Slash commands on discord.py

There are two ways of doing this, either by using [Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client) from `discord` or [Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) from `discord.ext.commands`.

[discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client) method:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="mycommand", description="command description")
async def mycommand_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hello World")
```

Meanwhile, [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) has the property `tree` which is basically the same as [app_commands.CommandTree](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree). The main advantage of [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot), is the use of [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html).

Here is how you initialise [bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot).

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.default())
tree = bot.tree #  Or use bot.tree directly

#  Same command as above
```

`discord.py` has resumed development on `discord.py` after halting it over a year ago. After the announcement of its hold, forks like `Pycord` started popping up. For the question on which to use, it is up to you. But personally, I recommend sticking with the main `discord.py` library.

For more information on slash commands in `discord.py`, [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction), [discord.InteractionResponse](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interactionresponse).

### Deleting the bot's message

After replying to the command user with [discord.InteractionResponse](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interactionresponse) (which does not return a message object) you can delete with either the `delete_after` attribute, or by getting the [original_response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.original_response) object and then deleting it.

```
@tree.command()
async def mycommand(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=f"some message with tagging {interaction.user.mention}", delete_after=5.0)
```

Or

```
@tree.command()
async def mycommand(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=f"some message with tagging {interaction.user.mention}")
    original_response = await interaction.original_response()
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0)
    await original_response.delete()
```